# Deal with huge amount of data in Firestore in flutter project

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Normally, we use StreamProvider to deal with the data from FireStore in Flutter project like this:

```
  // I have a collection of Customer in my DataService
  Stream<List<Client>> streamCustomers() {
    return Firestore.instance.collection('customers').snapshots().map((list) =>
      list.documents.map((doc) => Customer.fromMap(doc.data, doc.documentID)).toList());    
  }
```

This is the Provider of stream data:

```
Expanded(
  child: StreamProvider<List<Customer>>.value(
    value: _dataSvc.streamCustomers(),
    child: CustomerListWidget(),
  ),
);
```

This is where the stream data consumed:

```
final _customers = Provider.of<List<Customer>>(context);
return Container(
  child: _customers == null? Text('Loading...') : _buildList(context, _customers),
);
```

I'll show all the customer data in `CustomerListWidget`. Because the data of `Customer` collection is very big (more the 10,000 - 50,000 records). Apparently this is not efficient solution. I'm wondering normally what kind of the practical solutions are used to deal with this scenario in Flutter/Firestore project?

**P.S.**: Pagination is definitely one of my possible choice. But there are some issues because I'll apply some filters to the data. For example, I have to query to Firestore every time when the filter criterio has been changed which will cause the data usage increased. And also it seems I can only use `getDocuments()` instead of `snapshot` to get the Stream data.

Comment: Implement pagination.

Answer (score 2):

I think using Pagination is which better fits for you. Implementing pagination in Flutter using Firebase Cloud Firestore database can improve your app performance and reduce bandwidth usage (which is one of your biggest concerns). There are some [articles](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/pagination-in-flutter-using-firebase-cloud-firestore/) about [this](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/pagination-in-flutter-with-firebase-firestore-96d6cc11aef2).